# Как можно сохранить картинку с помощью php?

Tags: php, mysql, изображения

Как можно сохранить картинку с помощью php?

Сначала получаем `image_id`

```
    global $con;
    $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user_images (image_user_id) VALUES ('$session_user_id')");
    $image_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

И патом как можно сохранить типа так `images/$image_id.jpg` и обновляем `image_url`

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE user_images SET image_url = $image_id WHERE user_id = $session_user_id");
```

PHP код

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 200;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = $_FILES['image']['name'].'.jpg';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: А вопрос то в чем? Что именно не работает?

Comment: Путем неявных умозаключений из текста поста, я сделал вывод, что автору нужно сохранить картинку в файл, а не выводить в браузер.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev работает но не могу сохранить как файл

Comment: Принимаю заявки на игру в экстрасенсов =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем вопросе уже есть ответ. Но я хотел бы подкорректировать.

Используйте преобразование в `int` для пущей безопасности: `imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, (int)$_POST['x'], (int)$_POST['y'],  $targ_w, $targ_h, (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);`.

Кроме всего, вы уже используете функцию `imagejpeg`, документация по которой находиться [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php).

Чтобы всё заработало, поменяйте второй параметр этой функции: `imagejpeg($dst_r, 'images/' . $image_id . '.jpg', $jpeg_quality);`, также нужно убрать `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');`, если вывод изображения не планируется. Иначе браузер всегда будет предлагать сохранить изображение, или будет показывать "битое изображение".

Comment: Спасибо так точно!